# Insert caption method in VB/VBscript

Tags: vba, vbscript, cpu-word

I am trying to format an inserted image caption using vbscript. I have tried the following but it doesn't work. I couldn't find any InsertCaption method that allows font formatting. On some forums I did find out that its possible to change caption style from word settings but couldn't find a vb code for the same and in any case that is ineffecient. I am trying the following. The first line works perfectly. The rest has no impact.

```
objselection.InsertCaption "Figure", ": " & Object_Title , "", wdCaptionPositionAbove
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(107, 143, 122)
objSelection.Font.Name = FontNameCaption
objSelection.Font.Size = FontSizeCaption
objSelection.Font.Style = FontColorCaption
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this via [tag:word-vba] or [tag:vbscript] because that is two(2) different things.

Answer (score 0):

The inserted caption does not become part of the image or the selection. It's just another paragraph with a particular format. You could do something like this to change the formatting of all captions:

```
For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
  If para.Style = "Caption" Then
    With para.Range
      .Font.Color = RGB(107, 143, 122)
      .Font.Name  = FontNameCaption
      .Font.Size  = FontSizeCaption
      .Font.Style = FontColorCaption
    End With
  End If
Next
```

However, a better approach would be to modify the "Caption" style in your document template, so that you don't need to modify the caption format afterwards.